# Join map keys in golang

Tags: go

I want to join all of the keys of a map into a single string of the form [k1, k2, ...].  I'm not overly concerned with the order, just that I can make the string.  I know that there is the function `strings.Join()` but it takes in a `[]string` and not a `map[string]bool`.

I want to do this in the most efficient/fastest way possible (i.e. I don't want to create an entire copy of the keys just so I can slice over it).  I couldn't find a way to just get a slice of the map's keys, so I came up with the following function instead.  Obviously it's not the greatest because it does an unnecessary write and trunc.

Is there a way to just slice over the map keys?

```
func CreateStringArray(myMap map[string]bool) string {
    if myMap == nil || len(myMap) == 0 {
        return "[ ]"
    }

    buf := bytes.NewBufferString("[")

    for k, _ := range myMap {
        buf.WriteString(k)
        buf.WriteString(", ")
    }

    buf.Truncate(buf.Len() - 2)
    buf.WriteString("]")

    return buf.String()
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most of the time, I'd just write the obvious code:

```
func KeysString(m map[string]bool) string {
    keys := make([]string, 0, len(m))
    for k := range m {
        keys = append(keys, k)
    }
    return "[" + strings.Join(keys, ", ") + "]"
}
```

If you need efficiency more than readability, you can look at the implementation of [`strings.Join`](http://golang.org/src/strings/strings.go?s=9356:9396#L372) for an idea on how to write this minimising copies. The main difference between this and your code is that a `[]byte` of exactly the right length is constructed which prevents the data being copied around when the buffer has to resize as the result is getting built up.

```
func KeysString(m map[string]bool) string {
    if len(m) == 0 {
        return "[]"
    }
    n := 2 * len(m)  // (len-1) commas (", "), and one each of "[" and "]".
    for k := range m {
        n += len(k)
    }
    b := make([]byte, n)
    bp := copy(b, "[")
    first := true
    for k := range m {
        if !first {
            bp += copy(b[bp:], ", ")
        }
        bp += copy(b[bp:], k)
        first = false
    }
    bp += copy(b[bp:], "]")
    return string(b)
}
```

Of course, be sure to profile and optimise in the context of the code you're using this function to make sure the readability tradeoff is actually worth it.

Comment: Honestly, I'd just use a normal "+=" and downslice unless profiling proved it was a bottleneck.

Comment: Yah, it's just odd that there's no m.Keys() to be able to provide to the strings.Join, especially given that you can `range` iterate over the map.

Comment: Go doesn't have many syntactic sugars. It can be done in four lines.

Comment: Well, this merged with the fact that Golang doesn't have real sets. this means that something as simple as '|'.join(set(list)) in python becomes: create map[string]struct{}, loop to fill it up, create []string, loop to fill it up, call strings.Join. So one line turned into two loops and 10 lines.